# Configure Oracle Db to use UniversalConnectionPool for JDBC

Tags: java, oracle

i need to configure my Oracle Database so i can use the Universal Connection Pool for JDBC. This is an old project. For some reason, i am getting the exception i paste below. Any help/tip will be much appreciated.

Here is the Exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at oracle.security.o3logon.C1.r(C1)
    at oracle.security.o3logon.C1.l(C1)
    at oracle.security.o3logon.C0.e(C0)
    at oracle.security.o3logon.O3LoginClientHelper.getEPasswd(O3LoginClientHelper)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.O3log.<init>(O3log.java:287)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:198)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:224)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.websitepros.sql.ConnectionPoolImpl.growPool(ConnectionPoolImpl.java:59)
    at com.websitepros.sql.ConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(ConnectionPoolImpl.java:109)
    at com.websitepros.sql.ConnectionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:43)
    at com.websitepros.sql.Table.getConnection(Table.java:164)
    at com.websitepros.matrix.dataobjects.tables.CategoriesTable.selectByParentType(CategoriesTable.java:434)
    at org.apache.jsp.keywords_jsp._jspService(keywords_jsp.java:287)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the last code executed:

```
Properties props = new Properties(); 
props.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout",     config.readTimeout()); 
props.setProperty("oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT",     config.readTimeout()); 
props.setProperty("user", config.userName());
props.setProperty("password", config.password());

for(int i = 0; i < capacityIncrement; i++) {
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(config.connectionURL(), props);
```

Comment: can you share the code that product this error please?

Comment: @YCF_L added :)